# How to test http.post in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, http, jasmine

one more question about unit testing in Angular. Sorry, I am new to this so sorry if the solution is trivial. I have this simple class:

```
export class HttpService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  postV2(url: string, request: IHttpRequestV2) {
    return this.http.post<IHttpResponse>(url, request);
  }

  postV3(url: string, request: IHttpRequestV3) {
    return this.http.post<IHttpResponse>(url, request);
  }
}
```

Can somebody point me the right direction how is possible to cover this functions with unit tests? Thanks

Solution: Thanks to @nate-kumar this is the solution that works:

```
  it('should call postV2 with right parameters', () => {
    const mockRequest: IHttpRequestV2 = {
      data: {
        cred: {
          n: "n",
          p: "p"
        }
      }
    }

    service.postV2("http://some.url", mockRequest).subscribe();
    
    const testRequest = httpMock.expectOne(
      (request) => request.url === "http://some.url"
    );
    expect(testRequest.request.body["data"]["cred"]["n"]).toEqual("n");
    expect(testRequest.request.body["data"]["cred"]["p"]).toEqual("p");
  });
```

Comment: Typically built in 3rd-party functions don't need to be unit tested (or more accurately are tested by the provider of the library). In your unit tests you only need to go as far as checking that they have been called, which you would do by mocking/spying on the httpClient.post method and checking to see whether the spy was called with your input data (e.g. `url` and `request`)

Comment: Yes, that what I was thinking - why unit test something that should be already tested. It is just my perfectionist nature that in my testing tools I now see 98% code covered and only those two lines remain to get to 100%. :) Can you please provide some quick example of what are you saying?